# How to make dropdown box out of menu

Tags: html, css

I have a menu for my website, how can I make it drop down too? The nav bar is the one at my virtual airline on ccvg(dot)net

We want to make it drop downwards so we can have other things there, such as an about page. Etc.

Here is the CSS for it:

```
 #bar {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:#fff url(images/barlogo.png) no-repeat 10px 50%;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    height:48px;
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    font-family:Corbel, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:14px;
}

#bar .btn {
    float:right;
    height:100%;
    border-left:1px solid #999;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#bar .btn a {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
    height:45px;
    padding:0 20px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#999;
    border-top:3px solid #fff;
}

#bar .btn a:hover, #bar .btn a.selected {
    background-color:#e6e6e6;
    color:#5c5c5c;
}

#bar .btn img {
    border:0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#bar .btn .value {
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-left:14px;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:20px;
}

#bar .icon{
    background-position:0 0;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0;
}

#barmenu {
    position:fixed;
    width:250px;
    right:0;
    top:48px;
    background:#fff;
    border-left:1px solid #999;
    border-bottom:1px solid #999;
    font-size:8pt;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-weight:normal;
    z-index:1;
    display:none;
}

#btn_menu:hover~#barmenu, #barmenu:hover {
    display:block;
}

#barmenu a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#5c5c5c;
    border-top:1px solid #999;
}

#barmenu a:hover {
    background:#e6e6e6;
}
```

Here is the HTML to make a simple button button.

```
<div class="bar"><div class="btn"><a href="<?php echo url('/'); ?>" title="Homepage" style="border-color: #40E0D0;">Homepage</a></div></div>
```

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/v3xLkvke/1/

Comment: That is exactly what I want! How could I make it work with my already made stuff

Comment: Ok, I have it appear when I hover over my button BUT, it appears on the left hand side of the page, in the top corner.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the HTML  tag. The following example is from w3schools, i.e. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Avoid citing W3Schools. It is a source widely known as incorrect and often wrong. Consider [W3Fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/) for more information.